# Coldfusion set time out in .cfc page?

Tags: coldfusion, settimeout, coldfusion-9, cfc, cffunction

I have one .`cfc` that I use for all communication between client and server code. This cfc page has about 10 different function. Each function has different purpose and I have queries for Select, Insert, Update and Delete. I'm wondering if I should set `timeout` on the top of the `.cfc` page inside `cfcomponent` tag or this should be set inside of the each function or do I even need this? In our current system we have some many error messages like: `The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFQUERY`.

I would like to prevent any similar error messages in my app. Here is example of my cfc page:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfset currentDate = DateFormat(Now(),'mm/dd/yyyy')>
    <cfset currentTime = TimeFormat(Now(),'hh:mm tt')>

    <cfinvoke component="appEntry" method="getRecord" returnvariable="CHKAccess">
        <cfinvokeargument name="user" value="userdata"/>
        <cfinvokeargument name="app" value="myApp"/>
    </cfinvoke>

    <cfset adminAccess = false>
    <cfset userAccess = false>

    <cfif CHKAccess.RecordCount EQ 1>
        <cfif CHKAccess.pd_hfmAccess EQ 'A'>
            <cfset adminAccess = true>
        </cfif>
        <cfif CHKAccess.pd_hfmAccess EQ 'U'>
            <cfset userAccess = true>
        </cfif>
    </cfif>

    <cffunction name="getData" access="remote" output="true" returnformat="JSON">
        <cfargument name="keyVal" type="string" required="true">

        <cfset fnResults = structNew()>

        <cfif userAccess>
            <cfquery name="getRec" datasource="tes">
                SELECT some columns
                FROM Test
            </cfquery>

            <cfset fnResults.status = "200">
        <cfelse>
            <cfset fnResults.status = "400">
            <cfset fnResults.message = "Invalid access attempt.">
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn fnResults>
    </cffunction>

   <!--- More functions below --->
</cfcomponents>
```

If anyone have suggestion what would be the best fix please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Is there an Application.cfc or Application.cfm in play here?

Comment: @DanBracuk it's Application.cfc

Comment: If you want to set a timeout on every page, write the code into the onRequestStart method of your Application.cfc.  Bear in mind though, that there is a default timeout on queries as well.  If you know which ones are slow, give them a longer timeout.

Answer (score 4):

You should set the `requesttimeout` in the method that contains that `long-running cfquery`.

You don't want to "punish" all methods for just one method. If you set it for all, how do you know which one is slow and which one is okay, unless you don't care?

Comment: Well majority of these cfqueries are used for a single record. But in some situations they can pull large number of records over 5 or 6k.

Comment: I'm just wondering what is the best practice for something like this.

Comment: Regarding, `how do you know which one is slow and which one is okay`, the ColdFusion Administrator Server Monitor can help.

Comment: How exactly does setting a higher than necessary timeout punish anything?

Comment: That's why I was wondering if one timeout can take care of everything... @DanBracuk